# Gparted no me deja redimensionar una partición

Tags: linux, kali-linux

He estado intentando redimensionar la partición para descargar un nuevo sistema operativo pero simplemente no puedo hacerlo. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien puede ayudarme estaría de lo más agradecido con ello.

Answer (score 0):

`GParted` es un programa que te representa el esquema físico de como están las particiones repartidas, es decir mientras la partición `/dev/sda2` se mantenga detrás de la `/dev/sda1` no podrás agrandar el espacio de la última mencionada, esto se debe a que en tal caso de agrandar el espacio de `/dev/sda1` estarías marcando la zona de memoria del disco de la `/dev/sda2` como espacio `sin asignar` lo que significaría que los datos de la partición se estarían sobrescribiendo al tener el `swap` ya creado es algo tedioso, entra en modo `root` para así poder tocar la del `swap` redimensiónala y luego redimensionas `/dev/sda1`